# Is there a way to call a method with parameters in data on vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, methods, vuejs2

I have a method with parameters and I would like to have the result in data (instead to use it in curly brackets on html). I'm not sure if is possible or what. This is an example of what I want to achieve:

--edit-- I don't need a multiple functions, I need to use only one and use it with parameters--

html

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="data1">
  <input type="number" v-model="data2">

  <p>result: {{result1}}</p>
  <p>result: {{result2}}</p>
</div>
```

vue

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
      return {
        data1: '',
        data2: '',
        result1: this.sum(1, this.data1),
        result2: this.sum(1, this.data2),
      } 
  },
  methods: {
    sum(number1, number2){
      return number1 + number2
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

Your issue is that your are referring to `this.data` inside of data, before `data` has been initialized.

Use `computed` instead of data or methods.

You can also just call your methods from the template if you need to use `data` as a parameter.

```html
 <p>result: {{ sum(data1, 1 }}</p>
 <p>result: {{ sum(data2, 1) }}</p>
```

See the snippet.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data1: '',
      data2: '',
      result1: this.sum(1, 1),
      result2: this.sum(2, 2),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sum(number1, number2) {
      return number1 + number2
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computed1() {
      return this.data1 * 1
    },
    computed2() {
      return this.data2 * 2
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="data1">
  <input type="number" v-model="data2">

  <h1> Method from Template </h1>
  <p>result: {{ sum(data1, 1) }}</p>
  <p>result: {{ sum(data2, 2) }}</p>

  <h1> Method from Computed </h1>
  <p>c-result: {{computed1}}</p>
  <p>c-result: {{computed2}}</p>

  <h1> Invoked From Data Init </h1>
  <p>result: {{result1}}</p>
  <p>result: {{result2}}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Please remove the calculations from the `data` object. This is a classic use case for a computed property.

Comment: I already added a computed case, However, I am still showing that you can call methods from inside `data`.  That was the question (can you call methods with params from data...)

Comment: You've added it just as I clicked "add comment" ;D

Comment: I need to have only one method (or computed) beacuse is a big function. For that I need to use parameters. Seems I can't use parameters in computed property..

Comment: Why can't you call your functions from the template with parameters then? `{{ sum(data1,1) }}`

Comment: Steven Spungin, yeah is what I'm doing at the moment, but the function is complex and it is not the best to handles with a dozen conditionals depending on user input values. My aim was to save somewhere the value. I believe I'll try to pass the functions as a props in few components!

Answer (score 1):

### TL;RD:

## 1. You TOTALLY CAN

## 2. You probably shouldn't

#### 1. Here is a way to make it work.

Instead of responding with a value, sum responds with a function. This allows the value to change without any reactivity at work. (more on this later)

Instead of passing a value to the sum function, pass the pointer (a string name that can be looked up)

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",
data() {
    return {
        data1: "",
        data2: "",
        result1: this.sum("data1", 1),
        result2: this.sum("data2", 3.2)
    };
},
methods: {
    sum(number1, number2) {
        return function() {
            var n1 = this[number1] || 0;
            return Number.parseFloat(n1) + Number.parseFloat(number2);
        };
    }
},
computed: {
    computed1() {
        return this.data1 * 1;
    },
    computed2() {
        return this.data2 * 2;
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="data1">
  <input type="number" v-model="data2">

  <p>result: {{result1()}}</p>
  <p>result: {{result2()}}</p>
</div>
```

#### 2. why you shouldn't

Vue handles reactivity unternaly using computed and watch. whenever you have a function in your template (assuming it's outside of an `v-if` statement) it will get computed **every** time the component is re-rendered. With a simple function like the `sum` example, that may not be a big deal, but when you have more complex functions, handling it using a computed value (or a watch) will only re-calculate the parts that changed.

For example if you change `data1`, `result1` and `result2` will get re-calculated. If you use a computed, only `result1` will get re-calculated.

Comment: Good explaination. Thanks.